# Is it possible to get first n characters with regex but end only with whole word?

Tags: java, regex

I need to get first characters from given string, up to given amount, but ending with whole word. I can solve it by splitting at word boundaries and append word by word in a loop until total length surpasses threshold.

I'm wondering, is it possible to do it entirely with regex, without loop?
I know how to select n characters (`.{n}`) or n whole words (`(\w+){n}`), but not how to choose some words up to n characters in total.

For example, if I have n=17 and text is `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`, then output should be `The quick brown` (15<17 characters), because `The quick brown fox` is already bigger than required (19>17 characters).

Comment: Can you give an example of input-output?

Comment: Isn't it easy to use `substring` in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say maybe like:

```
^.{1,17}(?!\S)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZGGnE/1). Depending on your samples you may need to be more explicit, but with the given data it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Does the job. How could I not think of this easy solution myself... In case some special chars need to be included in words, `.` and `\S` could be modified accordingly.